Looking for a software (Ubuntu) to create a encyclopedia-like structure (offline)
I'm working on a book (encyclopedia). What I'm looking for is an offline program under Ubuntu that will allow to create a tree-like structure and organize a vast quantities of information in encyclopedia format (in alphabetical order) rather than hundreds and hundreds of notes in text files. Then I would like to export a whole encyclopedia to Word's DOCX (with contents)
I googled and found nothing suitable

Do you know how formatting works in modern Text editors? If so why not use nested levels of headlines and an index in libre office?

You could try AnyType

it helps organizing your data in various ways, e.g. with help of types and relations
Linux is supported
it can work in cloud but also fully offline


